# By seconds vs in seconds

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the difference in meaning of these two phrases:

> by seconds

and

> in seconds

I read the first sentence in a book.

> The plant was growing in seconds.

As a language learner I am curious to know if the meaning could be changed by replacing **in seconds** with **by seconds**

> The plant was growing by seconds.

It's an imaginary situation as plants don't grow that quickly.

Comment: The idiomatic standard here is *growing by **the** second* - except that in practice, "seconds" is too short a time-frame for many contexts. But there are plenty of written instances of things [*growing **by the hour***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22growing+by+the+hour%22) or [***...by the day***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22growing+by+the+day%22) (Each hour, or each day, one can see evidence of further growth.)

Comment: We don't use ***in*** for "ongoing, continuous" growth, only for a "completed" process. *The plant **grew in days*** means it *became fully grown* after only a relatively small number of days. *The herb basil **grows in days**, but carrots and potatoes take months to grow big enough to eat.*

Answer (score 2):

I struggle to think of a situation where "in seconds" can mean the same thing as "by seconds".

There isn't enough context to be certain, but the original sentence probably means, "The plant was growing **within** seconds", as in, almost immediately after doing something to the plant, it started growing.

The phrase, "by seconds" usually means how something is measured. Here's an idiomatic example:

> Martin Fagan won the Manchester Road Race, one year after missing the top spot **by seconds**.

Here, it means in the previous year, Martin Fagan had lost the race, and the gap was less than a minute.

"By seconds" doesn't fit in this sentence or in your original sentence.

Comment: could you please elaborate if the phrase "by seconds" only used in some sort of competitions, games, etc where we have to measure some gap.

Comment: @Learner I can't think of any context where it's naturally used to express anything other than measuring a gap, but there may be some that haven't occurred to me yet. The gap measurement doesn't have to be a competition though: "*I submitted my essay so close to the deadline that I just got in **by seconds***." In searching, I've found other usages, such as: "*He told me he plans a rehearsal **by seconds**, especially when on tour.*" The meaning is clear, but I find this unnatural. I would express it: ""He told me he plans a rehearsal **by the second/to the second**...*".